# GraphQLGatewayModule context has raw IncomingMessage instead of Express.Request

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

When I declare the following within `GatewayModuleOptions.server`:

```
context: ({ req, res }): ExpressContext => {
   console.log(req);
   return { req, res };
},
```

the request object that is logged is an `IncomingMessage` instead of an `Express.Request` object (noted by the lack of `req.cookies`). According to [The Apollo Server Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#middleware-specific-context-fields), when using `apollo-server-express` the context should include an Express.Request object.

My configuration is as follows:

```
        "apollo-server-core": "^3.5.0",
        "apollo-server-express": "^3.5.0",
```

Is there any additional configuration I am missing to enable those specific types? I am loosely following a combination of the guides [NestJS GraphQL quickstart](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start) and [NestJS Graphql Federation](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/federation#sharing-context). They do not mention any additional setup other than npm installing apollo-server-express.

I have confirmed through debugging that NestJS is using the `ApolloServer` defined in `apollo-server-express`

Answer (score 0):

I was interpreting the logs incorrectly. The reason the cookies weren't populated was because the service was missing the `cookie-parser` library. The ref to IncomingMessage when logging the entire request appears to be a red herring, as the request has data corresponding to express.Request